# Send a request with Django view using Python-Requests

Tags: python, django, python-requests

I'm trying to create a simple microservice structure on my Django projecjt: so when a certain Django view is called, this view will send a JSON post request to a Flask microservice containing some user's data; the Flask microservice should receive the request, take that user's data and send back to Django some additional data using Requests again, so that my Django view can receive that data and perform some operations, such as showing it to the user.

Right now i'm just sending some dummy data, to test if this whole system ( Django > request to Flask > Flask > Request to Django) works, but i'm having some problems.

To debug my code, i'm trying to just print the received data. Here is my view:

```
def myView(request):

    mydict = {}

    # The request is sent to my external Python script..
    req = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', json={"one": 1}) # Some dummy data

    # .. Once the external script sends back a request with data, this should handle it
    if request.method == 'POST':

        # The data is inside this variable
        data = request.POST

        for key in data.items():
            if float(key[1]) > 0:
                mydict.update({key[0]: key[1]})

        print(mydict) #FIRST PRINT STATEMENT

    print(mydict) #SECOND PRINT STATEMENT
    response = HttpResponse(get_token(request))
    return JsonResponse(mydict) #RETURNS "{}"
```

And here is how my Flask app sends data (once it receives the POST request from the Django view) using the Python-Requests library:

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def test():
    # After the request from the VIEW is received, a request containing some random json data
    # is sent to Django
    url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/myView/'
    client = requests.session()

    # We need to get the CSRF token, in order for the request to be taken by Django
    csrftoken = requests.get(url).cookies['csrftoken']
    data = {"two": 2}

    header = {'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken}
    cookies = {'csrftoken': csrftoken}
    resp = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header, cookies=cookies)
    # Let's seend the request to Django

    return f"Test!"
```

Here is what's wrong with my code:

```
METHOD:  POST
{'two': 2}
[10/Jan/2020 10:41:37] "POST /myView/ HTTP/1.1" 200 320
{}
[10/Jan/2020 10:41:37] "GET /myView/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

Here is what's wrong:
Why does the first print statement return the correct data and why doesn't the second print? And why does `return JsonResponse` return an empty dictionary?

I tried to add `print('METHOD: ', request.method)` in the first lines of the view, here is what happened:

```
METHOD:  GET
METHOD:  GET
[10/Jan/2020 10:46:22] "GET /myView/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2
METHOD:  POST
[10/Jan/2020 10:46:26] "POST /myView/ HTTP/1.1" 200 320
[10/Jan/2020 10:46:26] "GET /myView/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2
```

Comment: The flask “API” that you call from Django should return the required data, it shouldn’t be sending the data in another request

Comment: @IainShelvington Thanks for your answe, so how do you suggest i should change my Flask code?

Comment: Can you share the flask view? It should probably just return the data in json format that the view can then use the data in the response

Comment: Why not just return `data` from your flask view?

Comment: @IainShelvington Because, how would my Django view receive the data? Flask and Django are hosted on different servers, it needs a way to send the data across, this is why i use Requests

Comment: When you do `req = requests.post(...)` in the Django view, `req` is now the response from the flask view. You should be able to access the returned data from this variable - probably `req.json()` if you are returning json data

Comment: So i should remove the line 'resp = requests.post(url, data=data, headers=header, cookies=cookies)'?

Comment: You should probably remove everything apart from `return {"two": 2}`

Comment: Ok, let me try!

Comment: That was indeed the way! I think you just solved a problem that tortured me for 3 days! Thank you really!

Comment: Is there any way i can reward you?

Comment: Added an answer, you can upvote/accept it if you like

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're flask view can be simplified to just return the required data

```
@app.route("/", methods=["GET","POST"])
def test():
    return {"two": 2}
```

Then you can use the data in the Django view after you have made the request to flask

```
response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:5000/', json={"one": 1})
print(response.json()) # This should contain the returned data
```

Comment: How to map it to pydantic object?